# Concerning $k \subset L \subset k(x,y)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, transcendence-degree

The following is a known result in algebraic geometry:

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero (for example, $k=\mathbb{C}$).
Let $L$ be a field such that $k \subset L \subset k(x,y)$ 
and $L$ is of transcendence degree two over $k$. 
Then there exist $h_1,h_2 \in k(x,y)$ such that $L=k(h_1,h_2)$.

> Is it possible to find $g_1,g_2 \in k[x,y]$ such that $L=k(g_1,g_2)$?

The motivation is the following result: If $k \subset L \subset k(x,y)$ is of transcendence
degree one over $k$, then $L=k(h)$, where $h \in k[x,y]$; see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/190920/any-two-bivariate-algebraically-dependent-polynomials-are-always-in-the-same-rin/191058#191058). Perhaps the arguments in that answer are also applicable here?

Please see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2540914/a-pure-algebraic-proof-for-any-unirational-surface-over-mathbbc-is-rationa) question.

Thank you very much!

Now I also asked the above question in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354080/concerning-k-subset-l-subset-kx-y).

**Edit:** Now I have found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400127/subfields-k-subseteq-f-subseteq-kx-1-dots-x-n-and-their-intersection-with?noredirect=1&lq=1) almost identical question.